# Exception detected while using GetPositionAsync Geolocator

Tags: c#, xamarin, geolocation, task

I'm getting an exception error: `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException`, while trying to get some geolocation informations using Plugin.Geolocator.

here 's the exception that I get : System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
  at Plugin.Geolocator.GeolocatorImplementation.GetPositionAsync (System.Nullable`1[T] timeout, System.Nullable`1[T] cancelToken, System.Boolean includeHeading) [0x004d3] in :0
  at interface_test.MainPage.CreateMainPageAsync () [0x0018b] in /Users/khalidharkati/Projects/interface_test/interface_test/MainPage.xaml.cs:140
  at interface_test.App.OnStart () [0x0001a] in /Users/khalidharkati/Projects/interface_test/interface_test/App.xaml.cs:23
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <58604b4522f748968296166e317b04b4>:0
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 () [0x00000] in <788a34f7a7b84486905dfde786529d42>:0
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <788a34f7a7b84486905dfde786529d42>:0
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <788a34f7a7b84486905dfde786529d42>:0
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.40(intptr,intptr)

To be able to use an async constructor, I made one with the position as an argument:

```cs
public MainPage(Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position)
{
    ...
}
```

Then I added this method to get my position:

```cs
public static async Task<MainPage> CreateMainPageAsync()
{
    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
    var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    MainPage page = new MainPage(position);
    return page;
}
```

In the app.xaml.cs file, I added this code to the `OnStart()` method:

```cs
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    interface_test.MainPage main = await interface_test.MainPage.CreateMainPageAsync();
    MainPage = main;
}
```

PS: Before I update some components, Xamarin and some packages, I start getting this error.

Comment: what is the InnerException of the TaskCanceledException?

Comment: @Jason InnerException (null) System.Exception

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , actually , this might sound stupid , but I just forgot to turn my GPS on , on my phone . that's it .